Why Ubuntu 24.04.1 only works on on one computer, but shows black screen after installation on several other computers?
For some reason Ubuntu 24 only works on my Super Micro X9SRI-F mother board.
Every other computer I own only greets me with a black screen.
Some of my computers are still on old legacy bios and some on UEFI.
I even took a hard drive with Ubuntu installed on it from one of the other computers that
failed to boot. Put it on the supermicro and it booted first try ?!!?
Why has every experience with Ubuntu needed a programmers advice to work properly ?
Now with the new version IT WON'T EVEN BOOT. Goes through the install flawlessly. Works flawlessly until I reboot. Then black screen. I've tried all the secure boot on off. Different OS in UEFI.
Nothing. I am not a programmer. Especially I'm not a programmer in Linux.
So I think this is the end of the road for me as far as Ubuntu goes.

I've had this same result on at least 5 different computers. They all work with windows 10. You can't tell me my hardware is defective. Every time black screen after a reboot. Then why Ubuntu 24 only works on the above mentioned server computer ???

Does it show the grub screen (which shows dual boot options)?

Most likely problem is wrong video driver.  Try safe video mode in the grub menu, or use nomodeset ; then once booted and/or installed, install the correct video driver, as described elsewhere I'm sure.

So the video driver works during installation and quits working after reboot ?  Yes obviously I am doing something wrong. Why does the installation on the same hard drive that fails on many other computers work flawlessly when moved to the supermicro server board !?  Exact same hard drive pulled out of one machine and connected to the server motherboard ?

@user10489 If there is a black screen at boot how would OP pick from the grub menu?  I was just building up courage to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ECM to 24.04.1 LTS but OP's experience is making me think to wait for Ubuntu 26.04 LTS.

technically, grub is before boot.  Practically there are timing issues there that deserve an answer instead of a comment.

Good luck and if you do work out the problem, please post your solution back.

I just don't get it. What has changed ? Up until ver 24 I have never had a problem with Ubuntu. Never. Something has changed that people don't want to talk about. The server board where I have 24 working is great. Everything works fine. The server board doesn't have it's own video output. I am using an old Amd Radeon HD 8490 1gb video card on that Super Micro X9SRI-F mother board. The cpu is a INTEL XEON E5-2650 2.0GHZ

Don't care about the machine that worked.  What do the machines that don't work have?

The latest one that failed is an Asus B85-E mb with G3220, 3 GHz, 2C, L3:3M, GT1, 53W cpu. 4g mem, 500g hd. Intel graphics. One of the other fails is Intel DH55TC mb with Intel X3430 xeon. 12g ram 500g ssd AMD Radeon 7800 series graphics card. Another is a Asus DH550C notebook. Not really sure what's in there. Just stock. Another is a Gigabyte GA-B250M-DS3H w/ Intel Celeron G3900, 8g ram, 256g ssd, Internal Intel graphics. There are several more which info I don't have right now.

Good news. I found another computer that runs 24. Another of my  DH55TC computers. I have 3 very similar setup to the one listed above. Differences include X3460 cpu, 16g ram, AMD Radeon C369 graphics card,

Found one more computer that will run 24. LGA 2011 SATA 3.0 PCI-E M.2 Slot 2 Channel Mainboard for Xeon E5 Core i7. I am using the E5 Xeon 8 core. 1tb ssd and radeon graphics card. So I guess more will run 24 than I thought.

will have to research this.  I've seen Radeon drivers do this, and I've seen the default Radeon driver fail.  I've not seen Intel drivers fail, that's interesting.

My newer computer, the B85M-E/CSM motherboard always bumps back to UEFI bios when trying to reboot. It never reboots 24. This is all using the same thumb drive install.
I found that some of the older computers I just wasn't waiting long enough on the black screen. Some of them did finally boot 24.

I've done hundreds of linux installs that end in a black screen with multiple video card manufacturers.  Every combination of motherboard, video card, and linux version has slightly different symptoms and methods to get around this issue, but the following procedure fixes the vast majority of cases.  Some parts of these directions are vague around areas that vary slightly between Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 24 but hopefully not so much you can't figure it out.
So typical boot from power up to linux ready would go through these steps:

bios power on self test screen and logo
grub (this may be brief or invisible)
kernel and initrd load (may be covered by plymouth splash screen)
video initialization (this is where it is usually black)
graphical interface initialization and login screen

If you have an nvidia card that is not well supported by the default nouveau driver (as well as several other manufacturers with similar problems with different drivers) the screen will go black at the video initialization step.  At that point, the keyboard driver may also in a state where it can't accept input, and the machine may or may not also be hung.
If the machine is not hung, you should be able to briefly press the power button and the machine will cleanly shut down over the next 2-3 minutes.  (I recommend holding the power button only as a very last resort.)
If you are booting the installer from a live usb stick, usually you can see the grub menu and pick the "safe video mode option" and then it will boot normally, but then you still have to fix this in the installed OS.  Sometimes checking "install proprietary drivers" will help prevent that.
If you have a fully installed system that doesn't get past the video initialization, the way to get out of this trap is to interrupt grub before it loads the kernel and change some options.
Unfortunately, the default configuration enables hiddenmenu in grub so that everything is pretty (but not functional), which means you don't get to see the grub menu before it's too late.
One way around that is to open a terminal window during the install and  edit /etc/default/grub (or /target/etc/default/grub) and change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE to menu and hope you are fast enough and do that before the installer updates the grub menu.
But if that fails or it's too late to do that, there are several ways to get into the grub menu anyway.  The most reliable one is to press ESC repeatedly during post until it drops you into the grub> prompt.
Once at the grub prompt, there's a lot you can do, but the easiest thing is to go back into the grub menu with the normal command...at which point it will go right back into the black screen and lock up.
So when you do this, type normal but instead of pressing return, take a breath, and then press return immediately followed by ESC which should abort the hidden menu and actually show you the grub menu.
Then select a linux boot entry and press e to edit it, move to the part of the boot stanza where it says quiet splash and replace that (or add) nomodeset which should disable the parts of the video driver that locks everything up.  Then follow the on screen directions to continue booting with the in memory edited entry.
Assuming all that worked and you boot into a useful video mode, you can then open a terminal menu and do some or all of the following steps:

Get rid of hidden menu mode so you can do this more easily next time:

edit /etc/default/grub and set GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE to menu
optionally change the timeouts to something longer
run update-grub to rebuild the grub configuration


Let Ubuntu guess what the correct video driver would be (frequently this works)

ubuntu-drivers autoinstall


Use the Ubuntu manual driver selection GUI to try each of the available drivers until you find one that works.

Open the Software & Updates tool
Select the Additional Drivers tab
Wait for it to populate the list
Try each of the drivers listed (reboot may be required in between) until you find the best one.  OR:


Do research on your video card and find the exact correct video driver, possibly downloading it from the vendor and install it manually (or use the above GUI to pick it)

If you did everything right, you should be able to reboot without nomodeset and everything should be fine.  If not, boot again with nomodeset and try a different driver.
If you can't find a driver that works, just edit /etc/default/grub and put nomodeset in the config file permanently and live with unaccelerated graphics and possibly a bad video mode until you can find the correct driver.  (In a few cases I've seen, this was actually a good option and not too bad.)
Sometimes you just have to wait a few months for a new (or less buggy) video driver to come out that works with your card and try this again.
Note that these steps do not fix things with every combination of video card and bad driver, but it works with most.  Sometimes nomodeset is not sufficient to disable the bad driver and more complicated incantations are needed (like blacklisting the bad driver from the kernel command line).  Sometimes the video card hardware is just bad and nothing works except removing it.  Sometimes it's some other driver locking up and you can hope removing quiet splash lets you see enough diagnostic messages to figure out which one.  Sometimes there are strange interactions between BIOS and the gpu that prevents you from seeing the POST screen and grub without playing games with bios settings and which video port you have monitors plugged into.  But you've not included in your question what motherboards, bioses, or even what video card models you have that might allow us to guess any of these issues.
Also, there are alternate methods at every step in this procedure that might work better on some machines, but this post is already long enough and those might be suitable for additional answers if the question is clarified with what step didn't work.

Thanks a lot @user10489. Regarding the gap to fill: did you mean the Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab?

Yes, that's it.  Thanks.
