NVIDIA kernel mismatch upgraded - screen unresponsive
I received an API Mismatch for my NVIDIA kernel (when running nvidia-smi) where the current is 535.183 but when I run cat /sys/module/nvidia/version I get 535.86.05. I tried to update to 535.86.05 but forgot to purge before reboot and now I can't even access BIOS or UEFI menus, the monitor screen is just completely blank (not even getting a signal as it searches for signal among its sources). My PC is a HP Tower Desktop with Ubuntu 20 on it. I can't even access recovery mode (I've tried spamming ESC, Shift, Delete, F1-F12 with no response). I don't know what to do since I can't visually see anything. And yes the computer is on, I've tried for hours now to resolve this issue but with no luck. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it?

Does anything in this answer help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526483/why-ubuntu-24-04-1-only-works-on-on-one-computer-but-shows-black-screen-after-i/1526511#1526511

Thanks for your response, unfortunately, when I add a USB stick to boot from, I don't get the GRUB menu at all, and spamming ESC doesn't do anything either except making the desktop do beep sounds :(

Sounds like maybe you have a timing issue and just missed the grub prompt.

Possibly! Is it ESC in that case that I should go for? Or is it any other like F12? Sorry for noob question but I get a bit confused about different answers from various sources

F12 or delete (or F11 or F2 or... depending on manufacturer) may get you into the bios screen.  Esc should abort some of the post tests and (if pressed enough times soon enough) abort the grub hidden menu (and possibly the grub menu itself).  So it depends on what you are trying to do.
